# Prove f,g are holomorphic constant functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be an open (and convex) subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f,g$ $\in$ $\mathcal{H}$$(\Omega)$.

If  $ $ $| f(z_0)|$+ $|g(z_0)|$ $\geq$ $|f(z)|$+$|g(z)|$  $ \forall z$ $\in \Omega$ $ $ with $f(z_0)\neq0$ $g(z_0)\neq0$

Prove that $f,g$ are constant in $\Omega$.

Hint: Use the function $ $ $f^{*}(z)=$$\frac{f(z_)\overline{f(z_0)}}{|f(z_0)|}$

Can I use some analogous of Lioville's Theorem? Is the only way i think i can get something.

Comment: The inequality holds for every $z \in \Omega$ ?

Comment: Yes it's already edited

Comment: Is $f^*$  a constant function $f^*(z_o)=|f(z_o)|$?

Comment: @Srinivas K, sorry i should've paid more attention to my question. The function is not constant i corrected it

Comment: I posted an answer i would be nice if someone could give it a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that

$f^{*}(z_0)=|f(z_0)|$ and $|f^{*}(z)|=|f(z)|$

$f^{*}(z_0)+g^{*}(z_0)$$\geq |f^{*}(z)|+|g^*(z)|$$\geq$$|f^{*}(z)+g^{*}(z)|$

Using by maximum modulus principle it follows that $f^{*}(z)+g^{*}(z)=K \in \mathbb{R}$ and the inequalities become equalities.

$g^*(z)=K-f^*(z)$

$|g^{*}(z)|=K-|f^{*}(z)|$ $\implies K-|f^{*}(z)|=|K-f^{*}(z)|$

$f^{*}(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ $\implies K^2+u^2+v^2-2K|f^{*}(z)|=K^2+u^2+v^2-2Ku$

$\implies$ $|f^{*}(z)|=u(x,y) \iff f^{*}(z) \in \mathbb{R} $

Then using Cauchy Riemann equations : $f^{*}(z)=u(x,y)$ and $u_x,u_y=0$ since $\Omega$ is a convex subset of $\mathbb{C}$ it follows $f^{*}(z)$
 is a constant function  $\implies g^{*}$ is constant  and finally $f(z),g(z)$ are also constants